# decoupling Search  Query Builder from WebPart Properties and running it with JavaScript

Tags: search, rest, query

I spent some time googling around .. no luck

### Goal

Am building me own flavor of the Content Search WebPart, it performs REST Searches [✔], transforms the results [✔], and displays everything in an Angular SPA [✔]

(*I am steering away from DisplayTemplates, which are a pain to build and maintain*)

**I now want to present the user with a nice QueryBuilder** [?]

would like to use SharePoints own Search Query Builder **without using the WebPart Properties UI**

### Analysis

The (REST) Search Query Builder

[image]

Can be started with:

```
Search.Configuration.QueryBuilder.launchQueryBuilder(
    "...[path to aspx page]..",
    "{bd690c55-070e-417d-9845-db531a89ef8c}",
    "1",
    3,
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "Full",
    "QueryDataHField_ctl00_MSOTlPn_EditorZone_Edit0g_f063d9b7_6261_4e85_9297_28a2ad8fabcd");
```

Once the Page is in Edit-Mode AND the WebProperties pane is opened.

It is clear that some javascripts need to load in order to load the global `Search` object.

### Question

Before I start hunting down which JS files are required, and figuring out what the parameters do

**Has any one done this yet?**

Comment: I don't know of anything documented in the wild, perhaps looking at the debug version of the js file might get you started? I checked https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.5528.1208/search.configuration.debug.js and it might be somewhat useful. `Search.Configuration.QueryBuilder.launchQueryBuilder = function Search_Configuration_QueryBuilder$launchQueryBuilder(rawUrl, listId, itemId, numOfItems, termId, termSetId, termStoreId, mode, inputFieldName)`